# Is it possible to have different build.gradles for different product flavors?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

The project that I am working is built for both Amazon based devices as well as Android. Almost of 95% of the code base is common between these two. So instead of making these two as different projects, I thought of putting these two together using product flavors.(Please let me know if there can be other better solution)

But one of the problem I am facing here is with the buildscript and android properties in build.gradle, where I will need different values for Amazon and Android.
For example, I need this for Android

`dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.3'
    }`

and this for Amazon

`dependencies {
            classpath 'com.amazon.device.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'
    }`

Similarly for compileSdkVersion and buildToolsVersion as well.

If I need to have two different build.gradles for each, how should I let one of them get picked based on the build flavor? ( I am not sure if it is really possible)

If not, is there really a better possible solution to fix this problem by placing everything in the same project.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: According to the Amazon docs, the point behind `com.amazon.device.tools.build:gradle` was to fix [a bug that was fixed a year ago](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=75407). Have you tried just using the regular Gradle for Android plugin, perhaps a newer version than the one that you have listed above? (e.g., `com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0`)? I don't know if you can override `compileSdkVersion` or `buildToolsVersion` on a per-flavor basis.

Comment: I just tried that but this xml namespace can not be retrieved
"http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/amazon"

Answer (score 4):

It should be a comment, but it is too long.
I will delete it if it will not provide an help.

As I know you can't have different `build.gradle` for product flavors.
However you should be able to condition the `buildscript` and the `compileSdkVersion`.

It is not so clean but you can use something like:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    if (condition) {
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0+'
        }
    } else if (condition) {
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.amazon.device.tools.build:gradle:1.1.3'
        }
    }
}

android {
    if (condition) {
        compileSdkVersion 23
    } else if (condition) {
        compileSdkVersion "Amazon.com:Amazon Fire Phone SDK Addon:XX"            
    }
  //...
}
```

Comment: Thanks Gabriele. But how do I get the condition based on the product flavor as buildscript and android get executed before that (correct me if I am wrong here)?

Comment: @SivaKumar True. You can't get the condition based on the flavor.   Hovewer (it is ugly... I know) you can use a property in  `gradle.properties`  or a variable in top-level file.
Something like `type = google|amazon` and then
`if (project.type == "google") {`

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti but how do I select that specific type in the build.gradle file after I have specified the types in gradle.properties?